# How to wrap a TOC entry in custom code

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc

I have a book in which I'm using `titletoc` and `tocloft`. I would like to be able to add some custom code to the code written to the `.toc` file. For example, I currently have a line in the `.toc` file like this:

> \contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {8.1.3}The Sagnac effect}{142}

I would like to be able to get the code emitted to look something like this:

> \contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {8.1.3}\foo{bar}{The Sagnac effect}}{142}

Here `\foo` is a macro that I want to invoke, and `bar` is some other argument to be sent to the macro. Is there some way to do this? `titletoc` seems to provide facilities for emitting code before and after the title (e.g., to change the font), but I don't see anything that would allow me to wrap the title in a macro. Is what I want even consistent with how TeX's `.toc` file works?

Would I do this by somehow inhibiting my sectioning commands from emitting a `.toc` line of their own, and then writing one myself somehow? If so, how do I get access to the 8.1.3 and 142?

Comment: Why use both [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) *and* [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last suggestion seems to be suitable. One can remove the functionality of `\addcontentsline` momentarily and then place your own ToC-entry. Make sure to `\protect` the macro in order to avoid premature expansion (if required), or define it using `\DeclareRobustCommand`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{tocloft,titlesec}% Not needed in this example
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[2]{#2 #1}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{142}% Just for this example
\setcounter{chapter}{8}% Just for this example
\setcounter{section}{1}% Just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{2}% Just for this example

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Remove functionality of \addcontentsline
\subsection{The Sagnac effect}
\endgroup%
% Write specific contents entry for this \subsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}\foo{bar}{The Sagnac effect}}%
Some text

\end{document}
```

The above minimal example has the following entry in the `.toc` file:

```
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {8.1.3}\foo {bar}{The Sagnac effect}}{142}
```